# I am using jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3 , but when i upload image of 8 mb it not generate error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3 , but when i upload image of 8 mb it not generate error and processbar continue

i can't understand what problem 
please help me.

This is my Code

```
enter code here
```

## Ajax Image Upload Demo

```
    <div class="container">
        <form class="col-lg-4" action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php if(isset($uid)){echo $row['uid'];}else{ echo"";} ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($uid)){echo $row['title'];}else{ echo"";} ?>" >
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Image</label>
            <div class="upload_image_container" id="account_image">
                <div class="image_preview">
                    <?php if (isset($uid) && $row["image"]) { ?>
                                <a href="assets/images/"<?php echo $row["image"];?>" class="popup-link" title="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>">
                                    <img src="assets/images/thumb/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" />
                                </a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <i class="hi hi-picture fa-2x"></i>
                            <?php } ?>

                </div>
                <div class="image_detail">
                    <?php if (isset($uid) && $row["image"]) { ?>
                                <?php echo $row["image"]; ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                No Image Uploaded.
                            <?php } ?>

                </div>

                <div class="image_button">
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button btn-sm" id="add_upload_file">
                        <span>Add file</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files" id="fileupload">
                    </span>
                    <?php if (isset($uid) && $row["image"]) { ?>
                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="delete_upload" href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $row['image'] ?>">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cross"></i>
                                    <span>Delete</span>                    
                                </a>
                     <?php } ?>
```

</i>
                            Delete</span>
                        </span>-->
                    
                     ">

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: 'server/php/UploadHandler.php',
                maxFileSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024,
                autoUpload: true,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|tiff|bmp|png|svg)$/i,
                dropZone: $('.upload_image_container'),
                pasteZone: null,
                submit: function(e, data) {
                    $("#account_image").find(".image_detail").html("<p>" + data.files[0].name + "</p>");
                    $("#account_image").find(".image_detail").append('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">0%</div></div>');
                },
                progress: function(e, data) {
                    var percent = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 10);
                    $("#account_image").find(".progress .progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", percent).css("width", percent + "%").html(percent + "%");
                },
                done: function(e, data) {                    
                    if (data)
                    {
                        var new_filename = data._response.result.files[0].name;                        
                        $("#account_image").find(".progress").remove();
                        $("#account_image").find(".image_preview").html("<img src='server/php/files/" + new_filename + "' />");
                        $("#account_image").find("#account_image_hidden").val(new_filename);

                        if ($("#account_image").find("#delete_upload").length)
                            $("#account_image").find("#delete_upload").attr("delete_file_name", new_filename);
                        else {
                            var button = '<span class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="delete_upload" delete_file_name="' + new_filename + '"><i class="fa fa-cross"></i><span>Delete</span></span>';
                            $("#account_image").find(".image_button").append(button);
                        }
                    }
                },
                fail: function(e, data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                processfail: function(e, data) {
                    alert(data.files[data.index].name + "\n" + data.files[data.index].error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what error you get? Also check the **upload_max_filesize** in you php.ini file.

Comment: check you php.ini settings for   `post_max_size,upload_max_filesize `

Answer (score 0):

First, you should include the `server/php/UploadHandler.php` file in your question.

Also, check for errors while processing upload. `$_FILES['FIELD_NAME']['error']` must be equal to `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` constant, with the value `0`. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) show other possible values and what each one mean. It will give a clue of what is the problem.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042362/php-file-upload-determine-error-or-no-file-selected#13042401) show how you can proceed.

Furthermore, check both **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** directives in the php.ini file. As said in the question comments.